# Why is the Firebase `accessToken` under such a strange heading?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-redux-firebase

## Background

I have authenticated a user successfully with firebase in the client.

```
let fbAuthCreds = await this.props.firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

When I log this I get an object full of very strange looking keys example

> Ac, D, Ga, Sa, Yd, ba, fa, g, refreshToken, vc, ze

Most of these I have no idea what they mean (except `refreshToken`, `email` .etc)

I found that the actual accessToken id the one that says `Yd`

## Question

Why does firebase send back such strange objects with non human readable names?

Also I would like to send the token to my node server but writing `fbAuthCreds.Yd` seems not right, how should I retrieve it?

## Additional Note

I did get this auth process into redux with `react-redux-firebase` (Awesome library) and can see a much nicer path to retrieve the data but it fails and says undefined when I try to get hold of it.

**Look at line 23-27** there are proper names for the tokens and they should be retrievable

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does firebase send back such strange objects with non human readable names?

The code is minified to save bandwidth and memory. Methods and fields that are part of the public API are left unmodified during this process.

Note that the minified names may change between builds, so you should not rely on them staying the same. Instead use the methods from the [public API of the user object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User), e.g. [`User.getToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getToken).

Comment: When using the function `firebase.auth(...).currentUser.getIdToken` I get a TypeError that it is not a function. 

this was part of the reason I had to look up the inner workings of firebase auth.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you posted a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). :-/ Please update your question to share the [minimal code that reproduces **that** problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suspect it might be a versioning issue, but am not sure. Note that the [Firebase Auth JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/master/packages/auth) was recently open-sourced, so we might have to look there.

Comment: Well the main point of my question was to discover the reason behind the unintuitive names of the firebase auth return. Which you nailed, so thank you. It did however reveal the obvious flaw in my current implementation. I'm sure there are already a bunch of questions about `getIdToken` returning null.